# JQuery Drag Drop Lists - One Direction Only

Tags: jquery, html, list, drag-and-drop

I've seen the examples of drag and drop lists as well as nestable versions (namely jquery.nestable.js).  They look great but I'm desperate to only make this one direction.

All the examples I've seen have two way drag drop.  Drag from Left list to right list and right list to left list.

What I'm after is a static left list (no sorting or reordering) that items can be dragged to the right list (without removing from left list).  This right list can drag it's items up and down but not out again.  I was going to have a x button on the items in the right list to remove them.

Is this possible?

Below is image of what I won't want to happen.

I'm currently using dbushell.com Nestable jQuery Plugin

[image]

HTML.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="js-nestable-action">
    <a data-action="expand-all" class="btn btn-default btn-sm mr-sm">Expand All</a><a data-action="collapse-all" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">CollapseAll</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="nestable" class="dd">
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li data-id="1" class="dd-item">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="2" class="dd-item">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li data-id="3" class="dd-item">
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-id="4" class="dd-item">
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-id="5" class="dd-item">
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 5</div>
                            <ol class="dd-list">
                                <li data-id="6" class="dd-item">
                                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 6</div>
                                </li>
                                <li data-id="7" class="dd-item">
                                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 7</div>
                                </li>
                                <li data-id="8" class="dd-item">
                                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 8</div>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                        <li data-id="9" class="dd-item">
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 9</div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-id="10" class="dd-item">
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 10</div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li data-id="11" class="dd-item">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 11</div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="12" class="dd-item">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 12</div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <textarea id="nestable-output" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="nestable2" class="dd">
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li data-id="13" class="dd-item dd3-item">
                    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                    <div class="dd3-content">Item 13</div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="14" class="dd-item dd3-item">
                    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                    <div class="dd3-content">Item 14</div>
                </li>
                <li data-id="15" class="dd-item dd3-item">
                    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                    <div class="dd3-content">Item 15</div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li data-id="16" class="dd-item dd3-item">
                            <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                            <div class="dd3-content">Item 16</div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-id="17" class="dd-item dd3-item">
                            <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                            <div class="dd3-content">Item 17</div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-id="18" class="dd-item dd3-item">
                            <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                            <div class="dd3-content">Item 18</div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <textarea id="nestable2-output" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is js I'm using.

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined){

$(function(){

var updateOutput = function(e)
{
    var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
        output = list.data('output');
    if (window.JSON) {
        output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));
    } else {
        output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};

// activate Nestable for list 1
$('#nestable').nestable({
    group: 1
})
.on('change', updateOutput);

// activate Nestable for list 2
$('#nestable2').nestable({
    group: 1
})
.on('change', updateOutput);

// output initial serialised data
updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
updateOutput($('#nestable2').data('output', $('#nestable2-output')));

$('.js-nestable-action').on('click', function(e)
{
    var target = $(e.target),
        action = target.data('action');
    if (action === 'expand-all') {
        $('.dd').nestable('expandAll');
    }
    if (action === 'collapse-all') {
        $('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');
    }
});

});

})(window, document, window.jQuery);
```

Comment: can you show what you have done...

Comment: I've updated with picture.  I have a list on the left.  I just want to stop dragging items back in.  Plus stop removing them when I drag them out from the left to right.   

Think a form builder type thing.  Type of objects on the left and you drag them into making a form on the right.

Comment: Have you had any success with this? I'm after the same Solution here